# Query Stackdriver Uptime Checks

Tags: gcloud, stackdriver

I am trying to query for the Stackdriver Uptime Checks using the google monitoring api. I cannot seem to find anything in their documentation that illustrates how to query for the uptime checks that were set up on stackdriver. Here are some of the docs I have been reading through. You will note that some of the query-able metrics include ***agent.googleapis.com/agent/uptime*** but this does not return the uptime checks seen on [Stackdriver Uptime Checks](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/uptime-checks). Below I am listing some of the documentation I have been sifting through in case it may be helpful.

Does anyone know how/if this can be done?

- [Google Python Client Docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/monitoring/client.html)
- [Time Series Query](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list)
- [Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a product manager on the Stackdriver team. Unfortunately, Uptime Check metrics are not currently available via the Stackdriver Metrics API. This is a feature we're actively working to provide. I'll follow-up on this thread when the feature is released.

Thank you for your question and for using Stackdriver!

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. Do you happen to have any ETA on if/when this feature will be implemented?

Comment: Any update on this ? I also need this.
I'd like to integrate our uptime checks metrics to our prometheus / grafana

Comment: It's now documented at https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-monitoring as uptime_check/check_passed

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that this metric can now be externally queried as:

```
monitoring.googleapis.com/uptime_check/check_passed
```

You can see it referenced in the [sample alerting policy JSON](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/policies-in-json) for creating uptime check alerting policies.